# How To Use External Class In YII2 Step By Step

Tags: php, yii2

So i have a class i have used  couple of times for other non YII projects but now i want to use the same class in a YII2 project. I have done some searches but i kind of got stuck along the way. Below is what i have done so far:

I created a folder called "utility" in the vendor directory, the utility folder contains my class named "AT_Response.class.php". So my question is how do i include or call and use this class in my model or controller.

I have checked some links like :

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-yii-integration

https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/not-understanding-how-to-use-external-php-library/79679

Class Code:

```
<?php

class AT_Response {

    static private $response = array
        (
        '9999' => array('description' => "Unexpected Response", 'definite' => true, 'status' => "Indeterminate"),
        '00' => array('description' => "Success", 'definite' => true, 'status' => "Success"),
        'NNC_AUTH_01' => array('description' => /*"Status unknown, please wait for settlement report"*/"System Error", 'definite' => true, 'status' => "Failure"),
        'NNC_VTU_01' => array('description' => "Ttimed out", 'definite' => false, 'status' => "Indeterminate"),
        'NNC_VTU_02' => array('description' => "Exceeded max number of requests for Phone number per time period", 'definite' => true, 'status' => "Failure"),
        'NNC_VTU_03' => array('description' => "Invalid target MSISDN supplied", 'definite' => true, 'status' => "Failure"),
        '-1' => array('description' => "Not successful", 'definite' => false, 'status' => "Failure"),
    );

    static function getResponseByCode($respCode) {
        if (isset(self::$response[$respCode]))
            return self::$response[$respCode];

        //else
        return self::$response['9999'];
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: add your class code

Comment: are you using `advance` or `basic` app ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I am using basic app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few changes you can use any custom class as a helper component. You need to use `namespace` and `use` statement for the existing class you have, see the below

```
<?php
namespace app\components;

class Response
{

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private static $response = array
        (
        '9999' => array('description' => "Unexpected Response", 'definite' => true, 'status' => "Indeterminate"),
        '00' => array('description' => "Success", 'definite' => true, 'status' => "Success"),
        'NNC_AUTH_01' => array('description' => /*"Status unknown, please wait for settlement report"*/"System Error", 'definite' => true, 'status' => "Failure"),
        'NNC_VTU_01' => array('description' => "Ttimed out", 'definite' => false, 'status' => "Indeterminate"),
        'NNC_VTU_02' => array('description' => "Exceeded max number of requests for Phone number per time period", 'definite' => true, 'status' => "Failure"),
        'NNC_VTU_03' => array('description' => "Invalid target MSISDN supplied", 'definite' => true, 'status' => "Failure"),
        '-1' => array('description' => "Not successful", 'definite' => false, 'status' => "Failure")
    );

    /**
     * @param $respCode
     */
    public static function getResponseByCode($respCode)
    {
        if (isset(self::$response[$respCode])) {
            return self::$response[$respCode];
        }

        return self::$response['9999'];
    }

}
```

Save the Above class in a file called `Response.php` in `app\components` folder if using `basic-app` or `common\components` if you are using `advanced-app` but dont forget to change the `namespace` in the code.

You can then call the function `getResponseByCode()` like `app\components\Response::getResponseByCode($responseCode)` or `common\components\Response::getResponseByCode($responseCode)`

Comment: I am new to YII, can't seem to find the app/components folder.

Comment: `app` means your application root, not an actual folder, if you are using basic app there should be a folder `components` into your application root, otherwise create one and put the file there.